# The best way to keep two branches in sync?

Tags: git

Suppose my git project have two branches **A** and **B**, now i'm on `A` branch, and commit two commits: `C1` and `C2`, branch `B` does not need include these commits so i did nothing, then i commit `C3` in `A`,  `B` should include this commit too, so i decide to merge from `A` to `B`, but according to my understanding `C1` and `C2` will be merged to `B` too, i have to resolve this change/conflict every time when i merge, right?

Another questions is, `A` branch is changes frequently(like above) and `B` is not that much, in this situation, to keep the two branches in sync, what's the best practice to achieve this?

BACKGROUND: Both `A` and `B` branches will be kept. At the beginning `A` is branched from `B`, but `A` is going to has its own feature, `B` is relative stable, they share 60% same code base. We are working on `A`, but sometimes we implement a new function and decide both `A` and `B` will be included.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you explain the purpose of those branches A and B. “In sync” would mean that they are identical, but it seems that B is supposed to get a subset of the commits in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick $SHA_OF_C3` to [port specific commits](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) from one branch to another.

More generally, your branching strategy will determine good practises. I think [Vincent Driessen's branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is at the very least a good place to start when you're designing your git repo governance approach.